# How would I use a node*create statement with a linked list?

Tags: c++, linked-list

Can someone please explain me what exactly "node *create(int element)" means on the code below. I think it looks like a function but I'm not sure.
I also made some comments so you guys can have an idea of what I understand from it.Thank you for any help provided.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct node { // linear linked list

  int e;  //data
  node *next; //pointer to itself 

};

node *create(int);    

int main() {
  //edited I think I got it thanks for commenting any advice is welcome
  node *myPtr = NULL;
  myPtr = create(8);

  cout << myPtr -> e;

}



node *create(int element) { //is this a function ?

  //all this comments below is what I deduce so far
  node *n;  //declare node pointer
  n = new node;   //create node
  n->e = element;  //makes 
  n->next = NULL ;  //makes pointer null
  return n;   //returns node

}
```

Comment: Yes, it's a function, but there's not much point to it. What you really want is a `node` constructor. Something like `node(int element, node * nextptr = nullptr): e(element), next(nextptr) {}` Now all you need to do is `node n = new node(42);`. There are times when a `create` function makes sense, but while it's harmless, this isn't one of them.

Comment: Usage of the function looks something like `node n = create(42);`

Comment: A note on linked list: before you write any code, draw some pictures. Draw a list. Then step by step draw all of the changes you need to make to the list to perform an operation. The drawings become your code and your best debugging said because if the code doesn't do what the drawings do, that's probably a bug.

Comment: Node create functions are generally used when each node is a struct with a large number of members that need to be allocated and initialized so that without a `create` function, stuffing it all in the `add_node()` function clutters things. Above, your create node simply allocates the node and initializes `n->e` to `element` (now imaging that `n` had 10 more member pointers needing allocation and initialization and you start to see where a separate `create` function can cut down on clutter.)

Comment: Another benefit with many members needing allocation is that each `create_node` function usually has a counterpart `free_node` function that handles the freeing and clean up of everything allocated in `create_node`. In each case is more about proper "factoring" of the code to make things easier to read and understand (as opposed to cramming all the code in one giant function and having to read through 300 lines from beginning to end). As the programmer, it is up to you how you factor your code, but the cleaner you can make it, the easier it is on you and whoever else maintains it.

Answer (score 0):

Your comments about what happens in the function are accurate.
Your use of the function is also accurate.

However, you created just a node of what could be a linked list. To create a linked list, you need more than that. You need to be able to create more than one node and link them together.

Done by hand:

```
node* n1 = create(8);
node* n2 = create(10);
node* n3 = create(15);
node* n4 = create(20);
node* n5 = create(30);
node* n6 = create(40);

n1->next = n2;
n2->next = n3;
n3->next = n4;
n4->next = n5;
n5->next = n6;
```

Creating such linked lists by manually coding creation of every node and every link becomes tedious. Creating `LinkedList` as a class and having member functions in the class to perform various operations on objects of the class will be right approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
node* create(int element) // yes, it is a function
{
  node* n = new node;
  n->e = element;
  n->next = nullptr;
  return n;
}
```

When you call create(), the node instance is created on the 
heap with new and the pointer to that node is returned 
with `return n`

`myPtr` is pointing to that node.

If you want to add more nodes then you will need to do
more work i.e. having a pointer to the first element
in the list and then appending nodes to that list.

it is helpful to create a constructor for node to initialize
the member variables instead of doing it outside

```
struct node
{
   int e;
   node* next;

   node(int v) : e(v), next(nullptr) 
   {}
};
```

so instead of

```
n = new node;
n->e = element;
n->next = nullptr;
```

you can now write

```
n = new node(element);
```